# can not open settings from GUI

Tags: gnome, settings, gnome-control-center

I can launch gnome-control-center from terminal without problem.
But I can not launch settings from activity by searching it.

My os information:ubuntu 20.04 LTS

after click settings from activity search result:
there is circle(loading icon) spinning several seconds. then .. nothing happens at all.. then spinning circle disappear ...

other applications can launch from activity search result without a problem:ie.vscode

Comment: I tried reinstall gnome or reinstall gnome-control-center.  does not help.

Comment: Hi guiverc, I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS. when I type gnome-shell in the console. It gives me org.gnome.shell already exists on bus and --replace not specificed.

Comment: " I can not launch settings from activity by searching it": describe what happens. Don't you see the icon? Do you see the icon but when clicking it, settings does not launch? Add all relevant information to your question: use "edit". Comments are not always read and can disappear anytime: they are only meant to help improving the question (or answer).